# Full version of the paper "Characterization of Temporal Property Classes"

Tags: reference-request, temporal-logic, linear-temporal-logic

Look at [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.38.2200):

E. Chang, Z. Manna, A. Pnueli.
"Characterization of Temporal Property Classes"

The proof of Theorem 8 at page 8 says: "We will outline the proof which appears in the full version of this paper".

However I cannot find any "full version" of the paper on any search engine.

Do you know which is the full version of the paper where I can find the full proof of this theorem?

Comment: Well, wouldn't it better to ask the authors?

Comment: Hm.. Good point :)

Comment: But, Manna died last year. Pnueli died in 2009, and I don’t know about Chang.

Comment: Ah, I see. Now it makes more sense. I scanned the list of different versions of the paper here: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=0&hl=pl&as_sdt=0,5&cluster=8399949500321300291 but I can't see anything useful. My guess is that they wanted to write a full version of the paper but they were busy with other things and finally forgot about it.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right... :/